# Trying to Write Move Constructor in terms of Move Assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So playing around with Move Semantics.

So my first look at this went like this:

```
 class String
 {
     char*   data;
     int     len;
     public:
         // Normal rule of three applied up here.
         void swap(String& rhs) throw()
         {
            std::swap(data, rhs.data);
            std::swap(len,  rhs.len);
         }
         String& operator=(String rhs) // Standard Copy and swap. 
         {
            rhs.swap(*this);
            return *this;
         }

         // New Stuff here.
         // Move constructor
         String(String&& cpy) throw()    // ignore old throw construct for now.  
            : data(NULL)
            , len(0)
         {
            cpy.swap(*this);
         }
         String& operator=(String&& rhs) throw() 
         {
            rhs.swap(*this);
            return *this;
         }
};
```

Looking at this. I though it may be worth defining the Move constructor in terms of Move assignment. It has a nice symmetry to it and I like it because it also looks DRY (and like copy and swap).

So I re-wrote the Move Constructor as:

```
         String(String&& cpy) throw() 
            : data(NULL)
            , len(0)
         {
            operator=(std::move(cpy));
         }
```

But this generates an ambiguity error:

```
String.cpp:45:9: error: call to member function 'operator=' is ambiguous
        operator=(std::move(rhs));
        ^~~~~~~~~
String.cpp:32:13: note: candidate function
    String& operator=(String rhs)
            ^
String.cpp:49:13: note: candidate function
    String& operator=(String&& rhs) throw()
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Since I used `std::move()` while passing the argument I was expecting this to bind to the Move assignment operator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `operator=(String&&)`?

Comment: It's not really hygienic to use the assignment operator of an object that doesn't exist yet, though.

Comment: It does sort of exist.  It has been initialized by the time the assignment operator has been called.

Comment: `throw()` is deprecated in favor of `noexcept` btw

Comment: I think you're going to have some sort of problem with circular logic.  I don't think you've actually implemented any copying logic anywhere.  You need `strcpy` somewhere in the program.  You can only go through so many levels of `swap` before something has to do the hard work :)

Comment: My semantics may be mixed up, but shouldn't `String&&` be an rvalue?  So calling `std::move` would try to convert it to an xvalue.  Shouldn't you just be able to call `operator=(std::forward(cpy))`?

Comment: You mentioned the Rule Of Three.  Does this mean you have `String::~String()` and `String::String(const String &input)` defined elsewhere?  That gives us two out of three, and you have your copy and swap for `String& String::operator=(...)`?

Comment: `operator=(String& )` and `operator=(String&& )` can be disambiguated by r-value reference vs. l-value reference; but not `operator=(String )` vs `operator=(String&& )`.

Comment: @SentiBachcha, that suggests that move semantics are incompatible with the use of copy-and-swap for the copy-assignment operator.  Is that true?  (Unless you do something else to disambiguate, such as a defaulted parameter or other such tricks.)

Comment: My little experiment seems to confirm Senti's assertion.

Comment: @SentiBachcha: My experiments also show that. But I want to keep the standard assignment operator `String& operator=(String)` so that copy and swap works as expected (in the most optimal way.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I only provided the methods that were relevant to the question (so it can be reproduced). All the standard methods are correctly overridden.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If I Remove `operator=(String&&)` then I loose my Move assignment.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am normally happy to call other methods in my constructor (I know the state of my object and know which ones are safe to call). I see no danger (or difference) here. But if you have a concrete description of something I have overlooked?

Comment: @KerrekSB: As it turns out. From the answer to this question(http://stackoverflow.com/a/18303787/576911) I know believe your first comment is ultimately the correct answer to the problem. Make it an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the copy constructor will have to be written:

```
     String& operator=(const String &rhs_ref) // (not-so-standard) Copy and Swap. 
     {
        String rhs(rhs_ref); // This is the copy
        rhs.swap(*this);     // This is the swap
        return *this;
     }
```

In C++03, the objection to this approach would be that it's difficult for the compiler to fully optimize this.  In C++03, it's nice to use `operator=(String rhs)` as there are situations where the compiler can *skip* the copy step and build the parameter in place.  For example, even in C++03, a call to `String s; s = func_that_returns_String_by_value();` can be optimized to skip the copy.

So "copy and swap" should be renamed to "copy only if necessary, then perform a swap".

The compiler (in C++03 or C++11), takes one of two routes:

1. a (necessary) copy, followed by a swap
2. no copy, just do a swap

We can write `operator=(String rhs)` as the optimal way to handle both situations.

But that objection doesn't apply when a move-assignment operator is present.  In situations where the copy can be skipped, the `operator=(String && rhs)` will take over.  This takes care of the second situation.  Therefore, we need only implement the first situation, and we use `String(const String &rhs_ref)` to do that.

It has the disadvantage of requiring a little more typing as we have to do the copy more explicitly, but I'm not aware of any optimization opportunity that is missing here. (But I'm no expert ...)

Comment: .. on second thoughts, I think there is one optimization possibility that might be missing here.  With `operator(String rhs)`, the calling function can see immediately that copy is going to happen (*assuming* it's required).  Assuming the copy constructor is inlinable and if the source data is already on the stack, this could all be optimized.  So I think it's advisable to encourage the compiler to inline the contents of `operator=(const String &rhs_ref)`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've just posted another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849080/146041) to this question which shows a simpler way to resolve the ambiguity.  Andy feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

It should be a rare occurrence that you try to write one special member function in terms of another.  Each special member typically needs special attention.  **If** after the exercise of making each special member as efficient as possible, you see an opportunity to consolidate code, then, and only then, go to the effort.

Starting with the goal of consolidating code among the special members is the wrong place to start.

Step 1.  Start with trying to write your special members with `= default`.

Step 2.  When that fails, then customize each one that can not be written with `= default`.

Step 3.  Write tests to confirm that Step 2 is working.

Step 4.  Once Step 3 is done, see if there are code consolidations you can make without sacrificing performance.  This may involve writing performance tests.

Jumping straight to Step 4 is error prone, and often leads to significant performance penalties.

Here is Step 2 for your example:

```
#include <algorithm>

 class String
 {
     char*   data;
     int     len;
     public:
         String() noexcept
            : data(nullptr)
            , len(0)
            {}

         ~String()
         {
            delete [] data;
         }

         String(const String& cpy)
            : data(new char [cpy.len])
            , len(cpy.len)
         {
            std::copy(cpy.data, cpy.data+cpy.len, data);
         }

         String(String&& cpy) noexcept
            : data(cpy.data)
            , len(cpy.len)
         {
            cpy.data = nullptr;
            cpy.len = 0;
         }

         String& operator=(const String& rhs)
         {
            if (this != &rhs)
            {
                if (len != rhs.len)
                {
                    delete [] data;
                    data = nullptr;
                    len = 0;
                    data = new char[rhs.len];
                    len = rhs.len;
                }
                std::copy(rhs.data, rhs.data+rhs.len, data);
            }
            return *this;
         }

         String& operator=(String&& rhs) noexcept
         {
            delete [] data;
            data = nullptr;
            len = 0;
            data = rhs.data;
            len = rhs.len;
            rhs.data = nullptr;
            rhs.len = 0;
            return *this;
         }

         void swap(String& rhs) noexcept
         {
            std::swap(data, rhs.data);
            std::swap(len,  rhs.len);
         }
};
```

**Update**

It should be noted that in C++98/03 one can not successfully overload functions whose parameters differ only between by-value and by-reference.  For example:

```
void f(int);
void f(int&);

int
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f(i);
}

test.cpp:8:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(i);
    ^
test.cpp:1:6: note: candidate function
void f(int);
     ^
test.cpp:2:6: note: candidate function
void f(int&);
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Adding `const` doesn't help:

```
void f(int);
void f(const int&);

int
main()
{
    f(0);
}

test.cpp:7:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(0);
    ^
test.cpp:1:6: note: candidate function
void f(int);
     ^
test.cpp:2:6: note: candidate function
void f(const int&);
     ^
1 error generated.
```

These same rules apply to C++11, and are extended without modification to rvalue-references:

```
void f(int);
void f(int&&);

int
main()
{
    f(0);
}

test.cpp:7:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(0);
    ^
test.cpp:1:6: note: candidate function
void f(int);
     ^
test.cpp:2:6: note: candidate function
void f(int&&);
     ^
1 error generated.
```

And so it is unsurprising that given:

```
String& operator=(String rhs);
String& operator=(String&& rhs) throw();
```

the result is:

```
String.cpp:45:9: error: call to member function 'operator=' is ambiguous
        operator=(std::move(rhs));
        ^~~~~~~~~
String.cpp:32:13: note: candidate function
    String& operator=(String rhs)
            ^
String.cpp:49:13: note: candidate function
    String& operator=(String&& rhs) throw()
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That's exactly what I did (and showed in my question (got it working then tried to make it DRY)). What I have now is a call `operator=(std::move(rhs))` that I expect to bind to the Move assignment operator and it is not binding. PS. Learn the copy and swap idiom.

Comment: I completely disagree with `It should be a rare occurrence that you try to write one special member function in terms of another`. The Copy and swap idiom defines `operator=` in terms of the `Copy Constructor`

Comment: @LokiAstari: I know the copy and swap idiom well.  Some of what I've learned about it is presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18303787/576911  .  PS:  Concerning your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19841626/576911).  There is nothing special about the overloading rules as they apply to the move assignment operator or rvalue references.  You can not overload by-value and by-reference.  Not in C++98, not in C++03, not in C++11.

Comment: @LokiAstari I found this discussion on copy and swap for c++11 helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922138/is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom-still-useful-in-c11

Comment: @HowardHinnant: You should add the last part of your comment into your answer it is important enough that people should not need to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this as an answer so I can attempt to write readable code to discuss, but my semantics may be mixed up as well (so consider it a work in process):

`std::move` returns an xvalue, but you really want an rvalue, so it would seem to me that this should work instead:

```
String(String&& cpy) throw() : data(NULL), len(0)
{
    operator=(std::forward<String>(cpy));
    //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns an rvalue 
}
```

Since `std::forward` will give you an rvalue, and `operator=(String&&)` is expecting one.  It would seem to me that would make sense to use instead of `std::move`.

**EDIT**

I did a little experiment (http://ideone.com/g0y3PL).  It appears that the compiler cannot tell the difference between `String& operator=(String)` and `String& operator=(String&&)`; however, if you change the copy-assignment operator's signature to `String& operator=(const String&)`, it is no longer ambiguous.

I'm not sure if that is a bug in the compiler or something I'm missing in the standard somewhere, but it would seem like it *should* be able to tell the difference between a copy and an rvalue reference.

In conclusion, it appears that Howard's note about not implementing special functions in terms of other special functions would be a better way to go.

Comment: I think `forward` must be called as `forward<T>`, I don't believe it's able to do template deduction.  Also, It normally makes sense only in the context of perfect forwarding.  In this situation, `move` is the right approach.

Comment: I think you are correct on the how to call `forward`, but I'm not sure I follow you on the `move` part.  `std::move` returns `std::remove_reference<T>::type&&`, while `std::forward` returns `T&&`.  If you are looking to call `operator=(String&&)`, it would seem to follow that you should pass it the `String&&` you want (instead of an rvalue reference of something you've already dereferenced)?  What am I missing?

Comment: It depends what `T` is I guess.  We have to do either `forward<String>` or `forward<String&>` or `forward<String&&>`.  If you use `T=String`, then the return value will be of the same type either way, so I guess it doesn't matter.  Only if `T=String&`, will the return type of forward be anything other than `String&&`.  So  `move(..)` and `forward<String>(..)` will do the same (correct) thing.

Comment: I agree about the difficulty (and the frustration!) of detecting a difference between `String` and `String&&`.  I recently was hoping to find a type_trait that could tell is a type had a move constructor.  But such a thing isn't possible, for similar reasons.  A number of people have asked, without success!

Comment: I want to use copy and swap idium for my standard assignment operator that is why the signature is `String& operator=(String)`

Comment: @LokiAstari Understood.  But it appears that the compilers cannot distinguish between `String& operator=(String)` and `String& operator=(String&&)`.  So you may have to make a choice between using copy-swap, or not implementing your move-constructor in terms of your move-assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for adding a third answer, but I think I've finally got a solution I'm satisfied with. [Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/lmFlYI))

You have a class with both of these methods:

```
String& operator=(String copy_and_swap);
String& operator=(String && move_assignment);
```

The problem is ambiguity.  We want a tie-breaker in favour of the second option as the second overload can, where it's viable, be more efficient.  Therefore, we replace the first version with a templated method:

```
template<typename T>
String& operator=(T templated_copy_and_swap);
String& operator=(String && move_assignment);
```

This tiebreaks in favour of the latter, as desired, but unfortunately we get an error message: *error: object of type 'String' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted.*

But we can fix this.  We need to declare a copy assignment operator, so that it doesn't decide to implicitly delete it, but we must also ensure we don't introduce any more ambiguity.  Here's one way to do it.

```
const volatile String&& operator=(String&) volatile const && = delete;
```

Now we have three assignment operators (one of which is `deleted`) with the appropriate tie-breaking.  Note the `volatile const &&`.  The purpose of this is to simply add as many qualifiers as possible in order to give this overload very low precedence.  And, in the unlikely event that you do try to assign to an object that is `volatile const &&`, then you'll get a compiler error and you can deal with it then.

(Tested with clang 3.3 and g++-4.6.3, and it does the desired number of copies and swaps (i.e. as few as possible!  With g++, you need `volatile const` instead of `volatile const &&` but that's OK.)

*Edit: Type deduction risk:* In the implementation of the templated `operator=`, you might want to consider being careful about the deduced type, something like `static_assert( std::is_same<T,String>(), "This should only accept Strings. Maybe SFINAE and enable_if on the return value?");`.