# std::shared_ptr causing issues while copying objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class which has a `shared_ptr` member. The constructor of this class takes a `shared_ptr` object which is assigned to its member. Now the problem is, if I assign this object to another object of the same class, both point to same `shared_ptr`. And I do not want to do this. Here is the code which resembles the code I have, but when I do the assignment it crashes at the `shared_ptr` swap. Please help me to get this working the way I want.

If you execute line obj2=*obj1, you can see, the new shared_ptr gets created in constructor and then a call to assignment happens where swap will get the temp shared_ptr on rhs and ends up recursively killing the stack.

```
class A
{
public:
virtual ~A(){};
virtual void Test()
{
}
int i;
int j;
};

class C:public A
{
public:

void Test()
{
}

};


class B
{
 public:
B::B(const B& rhs) : m_Command(std::make_shared<A>(*rhs.m_Command)) 
{


}
B::B(B&& rhs) : m_Command(std::move(rhs.m_Command)) 
{

}
B& B::operator=(B rhs) 
{
    std::swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}

B()
{

}

B(std::shared_ptr<A> command)
{
    m_Command=command;
}
void Test()
{

}
std::shared_ptr<A> m_Command;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::shared_ptr<A> cmd(new C());
B *obj1=new B(cmd);
B obj2;
obj2=*obj1;
cmd->i=10;
cmd->j=20;



return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are containing `A` in `B` (composition), why are you also deriving `B` from `A`?  If `B` has both an *is-a* and a *has-a* relationship with `A`, your design probably has an issue.  And you are violating the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Your call to `std::swap` is infinitely recursive and causing StackOverflow(!). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922138/is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom-still-useful-in-c11), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/detailed-explanation-on-how-koenig-lookup-works-with-namespaces-and-why-its-a-go)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what's happening. I'm new to C++11, could you please post an example which works or tell me what changes do I need to make to the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::make_shared<A>(*rhs.m_Command)` is going to fail if `rhs.m_Command` is null.

Comment: What changes do I need to make for it to work in the above code?

Comment: Well, you could shallow-copy `B`. Or you could only initialize `m_Command` in the copy constructor if `rhs.m_Command` is non-null. Or you could make sure that all `B` have non-null `m_Command`. Or you could delete all of your code and replace it with "hello world". Any of these things would cause your code to not crash, or to crash in a different way.

Comment: How do you do shallow copy of a shared_ptr?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant deep copy. How would you do a deep copy on a shared_ptr?

Comment: By copying its pointed-to object.

Comment: That would not work for shared_ptr

Comment: Of course it would, as long as the object itself is deep-copyable.

Comment: Thanks, I did some modification as per your suggestions and it worked.